I am getting error 503 when trying to upload an image even if the BE and Postman are working
I am creating a request that takes an image file. The server uploads it to Cloudinary, and I get back the image_url. For some reason, I am getting error 503. Both the BE and Postman are working fine. I can create a request without sending the picture, and it works. Also, I can update and upload a picture, and it still works.
export interface ProductsInterface {
  quantity?: any;
  product?: any;
  id: number;
  name: string;
  producer: string;
  description: string;
  price: number;
  stock: number;
  category: string;
  subcategory: string;
  is_top_product: boolean;
  image?: File;
}

export interface ProductsInterfaceOut extends Omit<ProductsInterface, "image"> {
  image_url?: string | null; // Received from the backend (e.g., fetching products)
  category_name?: string;
}

interface Product {
  getProducts: () => Promise<ProductsInterfaceOut[]>;
  createProducts: (
    data: Omit<ProductsInterface, "id">
  ) => Promise<ProductsInterfaceOut>;
  update: (
    id: number,
    data: ProductsInterface
  ) => Promise<ProductsInterfaceOut>;
  deleteOne: (id: number) => Promise<ProductsInterface>;
}

export const ProductsService: Product = {
  getProducts: () => Api(service).get(route),
  createProducts: (data) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
  
    // Exclude 'image_url' and handle 'image' separately
    const fieldsToExclude = ["image_url", "image"];
  
    // Append all fields except for excluded ones
    for (const key in data) {
      if (data[key] != null && !fieldsToExclude.includes(key)) {
        if (key === "category") {
          // Handle 'category' field
          let categoryValue;
          if (typeof data[key] === "object" && data[key] !== null) {
            categoryValue = data[key].name || data[key].id || "";
          } else {
            categoryValue = data[key];
          }
          formData.append("category", categoryValue);
        } else {
          formData.append(key, data[key].toString());
        }
      }
    }
  
    // Append the image file if it exists
    if (data.image && data.image instanceof File) {
      formData.append("image", data.image);
    }
  
    // Debug: Log FormData entries
    for (let pair of formData.entries()) {
      console.log(`Create FormData entry - ${pair[0]}: ${pair[1]}`);
    }
  
    // Make the POST request with FormData
    return Api(service).post(route, formData, {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    });
  },
  update: (id, data) => {
    const formData = new FormData();

    // Append all non-file fields to FormData
    for (const key in data) {
      if (data[key] != null && key !== "image") {
        // Handle category specifically if it's an object
        if (
          key === "category_name" &&
          typeof data[key] === "object" &&
          data[key] !== null
        ) {
          formData.append("category", data[key].name); // Assuming backend expects category name
        } else {
          formData.append(key, data[key].toString());
        }
      }
    }

    for (let pair of formData.entries()) {
      console.log(`Update FormData entry - ${pair[0]}: ${pair[1]}`);
    }

    // Append the image file if it exists
    if (data.image) {
      formData.append("image", data.image); // Append the image file
    }

    // Make the patch request with FormData
    return Api(service).patch(`${route}/${id}`, formData, {
      headers: {
        // Allow FormData to automatically handle content type including boundaries
        // Removing manual setting of "Content-Type" is recommended
        // "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data", // Do NOT set manually
      },
    });
  },

Here are my create and update methods.
The BE is all good. I tried copying the update method and using it on the create; the result is the same. I get error 503, and I don't know why

Confirm Content-Type Headers
In your createProducts and update methods, it's good that you're not setting the "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" manually. However, some servers require additional headers, such as Content-Length, mainly if the payload includes a file. You could also try explicitly setting Content-Type to undefined (this allows Axios to manage it automatically):
headers: {
  "Content-Type": undefined,
  Accept: "application/json",
},

If the server cannot handle multipart/form-data, try sending it with a JSON payload to confirm whether that affects the 503 error. Hope this will help
